# UIView within StackView - Position of Layers

Tags: ios, swift

I'm pretty new to Swift and coding in general. I'm trying to just create 4 simple grey circles that are positioned within 4 UIViews that are inside 2 stackViews...etc

With the 4 UIViews, I have them basically in a grid square in the centre of the screen, I'll add a screenshot for clarity below. At the moment, it seems to render the bottom circles quite far below the boxes that I have laid out in the XCode IB.

I've tried a few different ways of trying to get the circles positioned properly, but I've hit a brick wall and can't seem to work out why it's not working. I can get them to position properly if I add a UIView within the UIViews (Named 'topLeftBox', 'topRightBox'...etc). And whilst it's a simple work around, I'm just trying to understand why I can't just add the layers in the original 4 UIViews.

Any help would be much appreciated, and apologies in advance for the glaring Newbie mistakes!

Heres a screenshot of the output as the code stands now and also the XCodeIB:

[XCode Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftaFX.png)
[Grey Circles Simulator Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djaWC.png)

And here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var topLeftBox: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topRightBox: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomLeftBox: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomRightBox: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        drawCircle(box: topLeftBox)
        drawCircle(box: bottomLeftBox)
        drawCircle(box: topRightBox)
        drawCircle(box: bottomRightBox)
    }


    func createCircle(lineColor: UIColor, strokeEnd: CGFloat) -> CAShapeLayer {

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: 50, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        // Styling for the circular line
        layer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        layer.strokeColor = lineColor.cgColor
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.lineWidth = 10
        layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        layer.strokeEnd = strokeEnd
        layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat.pi/2, 0, 0, 1)

        return layer

        // Style the track

    }

    fileprivate func drawCircle(box: UIView) {

        // Create Circles
        let trackLayer = createCircle(lineColor: .lightGray, strokeEnd: 1)
        box.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        trackLayer.position = box.center

    }


}
```

Comment: There's a lot of variables that could go wrong.  Perhaps try setting background colors for your separate views to troubleshoot.  Also, you might want to have one (2-section) stack view centered, and then put two stackviews inside that, then put your UIViews inside those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
trackLayer.position = box.center
```

That is using the center of the box's `frame` which is in the coordinate system of its parent view.  You need the center of the box in the coordinate system of the box itself (ie. its `bounds`).

Replace the line above with this:

```
trackLayer.position = CGPoint(x: box.bounds.midX, y: box.bounds.midY)
```

Comment: Brilliant! That has fixed the problem I was having with the positioning. Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it. I had been reading something about the Frame vs Bounds, but the fix I tried wasn't having the desired effect.